# grails code-coverage cannot acces to method

Tags: testing, grails, code-coverage

I´m trying to do test in grails 2 with Coverage, but I cannot acces to method:

It said that:
 "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request..."

```
class UserController implements  ResourceLoaderAware{

def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    respond User.list(params), model:[userInstanceCount: User.count()]
}
```

}

```
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
    import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
    import grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin
    import spock.lang.Specification
    import com.snt.olucarodashboard.UserController
    import grails.test.mixin.TestFor


    @TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)

    class UserControllerSpec extends Specification {

        UserController controller=new UserController()
        void "Test the index action returns the correct model"() {
            when: "The index action is executed"
            controller.index(0)

        }
    }
```

What is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of instantiating the controller yourself, use the `@TestFor` annotation at the class level

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor

@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
@TestFor( UserController )
class UserControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "Test the index action returns the correct model"() {
        when: "The index action is executed"
            controller.index(0)
    }

}
```

Comment: A lot of thanks, now it can read my methods!!
But it said that:
"Failure:  |
Test the index action returns the correct model(UserControllerSpec)
 |
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:85)
 at UserControllerSpec.Test the index action returns the correct model"

...and the test fail in index method

Comment: Maybe the problem is partially solved using " import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional " in UserController, but then the error is: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [com.snt.olucarodashboard.User] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly"

How can I use Mock to solve it? Thanks